# What's the difference between title attribute and tooltip attribute?

Tags: html, xhtml

What's the difference between title attribute and tooltip attribute?  when should we use each?

Comment: There's no such thing as a tooltip attribute in HTML...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tooltip and Title both show information when the mouse hovers on a control. They both are used for showing tooltip text.

But there *is* a little difference between them. Tooltip is used in server controls (e.g., Asp.Net controls), whereas Title is used in HTML controls.

Comment: Right; maybe that's what got the OP confused. The `ToolTip` attributes get rendered as `title` attributes when the page is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Tooltip and Title both same. But both properly is known to be message information when a Mouse is hovers on any tool meaning that both  is used for showing the message.

Answer (score 1):

Title attribute provides the title of a particular image, text etc. only when the cursor is moved to the respective text or image. Whereas there is nothing known as a tool-tip attribute, a title attribute is a tool-tip which points to the title only when the cursor highlights the text. Although there is another thing as a title tag, which provides the title to a web page which is displayed in the title bar.